# Why in -COOH group the C atom pulls electron cloud from the OH group O where as the double bonded O pulls the electron cloud towards itself?

Tags: acid-base

[image: This picture belongs to Solomons and Fryhle Organic chemistry book]

Should both the oxygen pull the cloud as O is more electronegative than C . I think that as the cloud density decreases near carbon therefore it pulls . A proper explanation please .

Comment: It's wrong - mesomeric effect shouldn't be described as inductive.

Comment: In the book it is under inductive effect . We are dealing with electronegativity